# What is the correct Elasticsearch version to use with Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.1.4

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

Spring Boot 2.1.2 defines Elasticsearch version as 6.4.3 in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml.

However, Spring Data Elasticsearch defines version as 6.2.2 in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/3.1.4.RELEASE/pom.xml

So if we do not force the version, Gradle will use the highest version 6.4.3 for Elasticsearch libraries. Is it required to downgrade Elasticsearch version to 6.2.2 manually as shown in compatible versions chart at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not required to downgrade the Elasticsearch 6.4.3 version provided by Spring Boot as Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.1.4 has passed the integration tests with the Elasticsearch version 6.4.3.